# kubernetes Overriding environment variables

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I would like to be able to test my docker application on local before sending it to the cluster. I want to use mini Kube for this. Meanwhile, instead of having multiple kube config files which would define env variables for the cloud environment and for my local machine, I would like to override some of the env variables when running in local. I can see that you can do something like that with docker compose:

```
docker-compose up -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.e2e.yml.
```

The second file would only have the overriding values. Yes, there are two files but I find it clean.

Is there a way to do something similar with Kube/minikube? Or even something better ???

Comment: use kubectl contexts

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking how to pass different environment values into your Pods depending upon which environment they are deployed to. One pattern to achieve this is to deploy with [helm](https://helm.sh/). Then you use templated versions of your kubernetes descriptors for deployment. You also have a values.yaml file that contains values to be injected into the descriptors. You can [switch and overlay values.yaml files](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files.md#values-files) at the time of install to control which values are injected for a given installation.

If you are asking how to switch whether a `kubectl` command runs against local or cloud without having to keep switching your kubeconfig file then you can [add both contexts to your kubeconfig](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) and use `kubectl context` to switch between them, as @[Ijaz Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4550110/ijaz-khan) suggests